# Is there any better way to check for existance of several sub directories in C# than using nested ifs?

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

I am trying to check if all the needed sub directories exists using this snippet of code:

```
DirectoryInfo gccdir = new DirectoryInfo(txtgccPath.Text);
List<string> subdirectories = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in gccdir.GetDirectories())
{
   subdirectories.Add(item.Name);
}

if (subdirectories.Contains("bin") &&
    subdirectories.Contains("i686-w64-mingw32") &&
    subdirectories.Contains("include") && 
    subdirectories.Contains("lib") &&
    subdirectories.Contains("libexec") && 
    subdirectories.Contains("share"))
{
  //statements 
}
```

Is there any better way for doing this? In situations like this that there is a need to verify multiple conditions, what's the best way to avoid excessive usage of if else statements?

Comment: What is the type of subdirectories variable?

Comment: Also - no reason for check for the lib twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do like

```
if(new[] {"bin", "include", "lib"}.All(subdirectories.Contains))
{


}
```

etc.

Comment: I stole your idea, but changed it to not use to the List<string>. +1 for the good idea though.

Comment: Thanks, Whats that All() method doing?

Comment: All() returns true if All of the items match the inside condition.  In this instance, if all the items are contained in subdirectories.

Comment: It's a shorter way of writing .All(str => subdirectories.Contains(str))

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the other way round:

```
   DirectoryInfo gccdir = new DirectoryInfo(txtgccPath.Text);
    List<string> directorieslist=new List<string>(){"bin", "i686-w64-mingw32","include", "lib","libexec","share"};

    foreach (var item in gccdir.GetDirectories())
    {
        if(directorieslist.Contains(item.Name))
        {
             directorieslist.Remove(item.Name);                         
        } 
    }

    if(directorieslist.Count==0)
    {
       //statement
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] subs = new string[] {
    "bin",
    "i686-w64-mingw32",
    "include"
    };

IEnumerable<string> exists = subdirectories.Join(subs, 
    sd1 => sd1, 
    sd2 => sd2, 
    (sd1, sd2) => sd1).ToArray();

if (subs.Length == exists.Length)
{
// contains all
}
```

Comment: If you want to go that route, you can just use `Union` instead of `Join`.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of what Jonesy did,

```
DirectoryInfo gccdir = new DirectoryInfo(txtgccPath.Text);
var subdirectories= gccdir.GetDirectories();
var dirsToCheckFor = new[] { "bin", "include", "lib", "libexec", "share", "i686-w64-mingw32" };

if(subdirectories.All(dir => dirsToCheckFor.Contains(dir.Name)))
{
    //gccdir contains all folders in dirsToCheckFor
}
```

Only difference is that you don't need to make a list of strings for the directories in the folder.

Comment: oh yeah.  you could knock out the subdirectories variable too and do gccdir.GetDirectories().All()